# How to count instances a certain style has been applied via VBA?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

In Word one can click the pull-down menue of a style in the style-window and it shows how often that style has been applied throughout the active document. So this is an information which is readily available.

Is there any way to obtain this information via VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify exactly how you wanted to use it, but this should get you started. Found this at TechArchive.net - [Style Instance Count](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Word/microsoft.public.word.vba.beginners/2005-02/0277.html). These are two VBA subs which, with slight modification, you can count the style you seek.

```
Sub CountStyle()
Dim l As Long
ResetSearch
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
   .Style = "Strong" 'Replace with the name of the style you are counting
   While .Execute
      l = l + 1
      If l > ActiveDocument.Range.Paragraphs.Count Then
         Stop
      End If
   Wend
End With
MsgBox l
ResetSearch
End Sub

Public Sub ResetSearch()
With Selection.Find
   .ClearFormatting
   .Replacement.ClearFormatting
   .Text = ""
   .Replacement.Text = ""
   .Forward = True
   .Wrap = wdFindContinue
   .Format = False
   .MatchCase = False
   .MatchWholeWord = False
   .MatchWildcards = False
   .MatchSoundsLike = False
   .MatchAllWordForms = False
   ' plus some more if needed
   .Execute
End With
End Sub
```

Not sure what version you are using, but this worked with Word 2010.

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks for your answer. I am using WinWord 2007. My project is to read out the styles and their attributes into an Excel table, change them there, if needed and write them back. It works quite fine, the only problem has been, to delete unused styles, because I couldn't determine from within VBA whether they are realy in use. Finally I have written a routine that loops through all story ranges - but it makes the whole macro run for half an hour. - If I use your find and replace suggestion, what tells me how many occurences have been replaced? - Marcel

Comment: I'm not Luke. This is not a find and replace suggestion. The find and replace portion you are seeing is part of the VBA which resets the search to be ready for it's next execution.

Comment: Thank you CharlieRB. I commented on the code befor having fully understood it - never a good idea.